# how to multickeck in ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

multi checkbox not working in ajax calling it will reset,my checkbox like

```
<form action="#">
<?php 
foreach($rimdiameter as $rows) {
if($rows->rimdiameter!='') {
?>
<p>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="diametersearchs[]" value="<?php echo $rows->rimdiameter; ?>"  class="ads_Checkbox_diameter" id="diametersearch" multiple>
<span><?php echo $rows->rimdiameter; ?></span>
</label>
</p>
<?php } }?>
</form>
```

click a check box it will run a query and view the result and click next checkbox first will be unchecked ,my ajax code

```
$('.ads_Checkbox_diameter').change(function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
var final = '';
$('.ads_Checkbox_diameter:checked').each(function(){        
var final = $(this).val();
var type = 'diameter';
$("#loadMore").hide();
var siteurl = '<?php echo $root =  (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'; ?>';
$(".loadingimageproduct").show(); 
var serachfilterproductbyprice = 'serachfilterproductbyprice';  
var centre_bore='<?php echo $centre_bore;?>';
var bolt_pattern='<?php echo $bolt_pattern;?>';
var widtz=sessionStorage.getItem('widthz');
sessionStorage.setItem('diameter',final);
$.ajax({
url:"{{url('/')}}/serachfilterproductbyprice",

 method: 'POST',
data: {serachfilterproductbyprice:serachfilterproductbyprice ,width:widtz, siteurl:siteurl, type:type, final:final ,bore:centre_bore ,pattern:bolt_pattern , "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
success: function(data) {
$('#msgproductfilter').html(data);
$(".loadingimageproduct").hide();
$(".front_product_wheel_show").hide();
         $.ajax({
               //  save another data
                 });
          }
});
});
});
```

why the checkbox unchecked if another one is clicking time ,how to solve?i wand multi checking property . and it will sore in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you do in your `change` handler is explicitly un-check all other checkboxes:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
```

If you don't want to do that, simply remove that line of code.

Comment: how to store the multi select value in array